# window.onload and .click() not working in ie 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Can anyone please give me solution for this function,  it's not working on ie 9 ,  other browser it's working fine.

```
      <script>
        // prettycheckable

        window.onload = function () {

            $('.prettycheckbox .za_psb_checkbox + a')[0].click();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is your script tag for jQuery? You should just use `$(function(){ /*run your code in here */ })` anyways.

Comment: Any output in the console/error notifications?

Comment: You must provide a fiddle demo or SO snippet so that one can test it out in other platforms/browsers...

Comment: Do you have any `console.log()` statements in your code before the `onload` function? If so, IE9 might blow up because console is not yet available at that time in that browser.

Comment: I would recommend `DOMContentLoaded` anyway : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: there is no console error,  I'm using onload to click a checkbook to default  add to cart,  my client using this service https://www.zaxaa.com/, and this is the site link which is not working on ie 9,  http://www.checkout.allstardogs.org/checkout/

Comment: akhil viswam@@ have any solution to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.onload` only triggers when the entire page loads.So may be some of your DOM content failed to load in IE.

Comment: This is **HIGHLY** unlikely.. The window onload will trigger only when DOM and images etc are loaded.. But even if they fail, the window.load will be called after the last fail/load..